# Cannot insert the value NULL into column of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server with 9 parameters, which looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [log].[ADF_Log]
    @status nvarchar(255),
    @level nvarchar(255),
    @dataFactoryName nvarchar(255),
    @pipelineName nvarchar(255),
    @recordCount nvarchar(255),
    @errorCode nvarchar(255),
    @errorMessage nvarchar(255),
    @runID nvarchar(255),
    @inputParameters nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @statusid NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @levelid nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @pipeline_ID nvarchar(255)

    SET @statusid = (SELECT LoadStatus_ID FROM log.loadStatus  
                     WHERE loadstatus = @status)

    SET @levelid = (SELECT LogLevel_ID FROM log.LogLevel 
                    WHERE LogLevelName = @level)

    SET @pipeline_ID = (SELECT Pipeline_ID FROM etl.Pipeline  
                        WHERE pipeline = @pipelineName AND DataFactory = @datafactoryname)

    INSERT INTO dbo.LogPipeline_backup --[LOG].[LogPipeline]
           ([StatusID], [LevelID], [Pipeline_ID], 
            [RecordCount], [ErrorCode], [ErrorMessage],
            [RunID], [InputParameters])
    VALUES (@statusid, @levelid, @pipeline_id,
            @recordCount, @errorCode, @errorMessage,
            @runID, @inputParameters)
END
```

However, when I try to insert the test values with the following SQL code:

```
EXEC [log].[ADF_Log]
   
    @status = 'status test',
    @level = 'level test',
    @dataFactoryName = 'data fact name test',
    @pipelineName = 'pipline name test',
    @recordCount = 'recount test',
    @errorCode = 'error test',
    @errorMessage = 'message test',
    @runID = ' run id',
    @inputParameters='input par test'
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Pipeline_ID', table 'trosql-dev.dbo.LogPipeline_backup'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

What is the problem if the NULL value is a predefined value?
I don't see what the problem is with the script.

Comment: *Presumably* the subquery that returns a value for `@pipeline_ID` doesn't return a row, so it assigns the value `NULL` to the variable, and as `Pipeline_ID` cannot be `NULL`, the `INSERT` fails. The error is telling you the problem.

Comment: Thank you. but how do I set it up?

Comment: Set *what* up? What is "it"?

Comment: Your table doesn't allow NULL value to be inserted into column `Pipeline_ID` . That means there is no results for passed value `@pipelineName` and `@datafactoryname` in table `etl.Pipeline`

Comment: how do i allow it to receive null values? I try this:  DECLARE @pipeline_ID nvarchar(255) NULL 
but do not work

Comment: Please add the table definition for dbo.LogPipeline_backup as text.

Comment: alter table LogPipeline_backup  alter Pipeline_ID INT NULL should do it

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**
Change the column property to allow nulls

```
ALTER TABLE LogPipeline_backup ALTER COLUMN Pipeline_ID nvarchar(255) NULL --Assuming data type of pipeline id is nvarchar(255). Change the type accordingly.
```

**OR**

**Method 2**
Alter the sp to save empty string if parameter passed is null

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [log].[ADF_Log]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
    @status nvarchar(255),
    @level nvarchar(255),
    @dataFactoryName nvarchar(255),
    @pipelineName nvarchar(255),
    @recordCount nvarchar(255),
    @errorCode nvarchar(255),
    @errorMessage nvarchar(255),
    @runID nvarchar(255),
    @inputParameters nvarchar(max)
    
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @statusid NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @levelid nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @pipeline_ID nvarchar(255)

    SET @statusid = (
    Select LoadStatus_ID from log.loadStatus where loadstatus = @status 
    )

    SET @levelid = (
    Select LogLevel_ID from log.LogLevel where LogLevelName = @level 
    )

    Set @pipeline_ID = (
    Select Pipeline_ID from etl.Pipeline where pipeline = @pipelineName and DataFactory = @datafactoryname
    )


    insert into dbo.LogPipeline_backup --[LOG].[LogPipeline]
        (
       [StatusID]
      ,[LevelID]
      ,[Pipeline_ID]
      ,[RecordCount]
      ,[ErrorCode]
      ,[ErrorMessage]
      ,[RunID]
      ,[InputParameters]
      
        )
    values 
        (@statusid
        ,@levelid
        ,ISNULL(@pipeline_id,'')--**** MADE CHAGE HERE TO ACCEPT NULL VALUE***
        ,@recordCount
        ,@errorCode
        ,@errorMessage
        ,@runID
        ,@inputParameters
        
        )
END

GO
```

**In both methods, considered data type of column Pipeline_id as nvarchar(255). If any change in data type change the scripts accordingly**